# AttributeError at /notify/ 'User' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here in views.py When i am creating a user object . it show me and error **AttributeError at /notify/  'User' object has no attribute 'get'** How can i fix it out.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class NotifyView(TemplateView):
    template_name ='notify/home.html'

    def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        print('oye',request.user)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
        user.notifications.mark_all_as_read(user) 
        return user
```

if more information is require than tell me in a comment session i will update my question with that information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function name to something like "get_user" or "get_object".

Comment: I have asked new question and That is on deployment, please have a look, I believe you  can fix that, Thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65742988/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror-migration-accounts-0001-initi